# KENDO UI GRID and state persistence

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am using the below code to store the kendo ui grid to localstorage and then retrieve it back and everything is working fine.

```
function saveState(e){

             var grid = angular.element('#booking-grid').data("kendoGrid");
             console.log(kendo.stringify(grid.getOptions()));
             localStorage["kendo-grid-options"] = kendo.stringify(grid.getOptions());
    }

function restoreState(e){
          var options = localStorage["kendo-grid-options"];
          if (options) {
            var grid = angular.element('#booking-grid').data("kendoGrid");
                grid.setOptions(JSON.parse(options));
          }
}
```

Now we want to store this state in some persistence storage like DB and when the user login again we want to show to him his previous stored state from DB.
What i realized is that the produced json string also contains the grid data also and this data would have changed because data refresh happens every 30 minutes. This is resulting into showing stale data to the end user.

We want to store the current structural state of the grid without the data. Is there a way that we can achieve the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you getOptions(), but before you save, clear the datasource:

```
function saveState(e){
    var grid = angular.element('#booking-grid').data("kendoGrid");

    var gridOptions = grid.getOptions();
    delete gridOptions.dataSource.data;

    console.log(kendo.stringify(gridOptions));
    localStorage["kendo-grid-options"] = kendo.stringify(gridOptions);
}
```